# How to aggregate a views by only one field?

Tags: views

I have a views display that has two node ids: One is referrer and the other is the referenced.

I have only one case that the referrer make a reference to 2 other nodes. But when this happens I need to bring the referrer only one time with one referenced node, it doesn't matter which one of them.

Is it possible to do it? I tried with aggregate yes but without success.